# Java cucumber without feature file

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java, jira-xray

I am quite new with cucumber and I try to find on the web if it is possible to Use cucumber java library without using feature file from cucumber

What I would like to do is to instantiate Java object with Step definition in it (GIVEN/WHEN/THEN) from a string that will store my gherkin test.

If any of you have already been in same position it will be great to discuss it

Thanks

PS: I could use the feature file but I will have to do little more dev to retrieve it and write it on the disk as Cucumber is on my XRay company server

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not something possible with Cucumber right now and even if possible it would require a non negligible amount of work.

Have you read [this documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31622264) on how to use Cucumber with XRay though?